# How to do text-overflow: ellipsis in reverse?

Tags: html, css, truncate

This CSS:

```
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

Changes **"StartOfLineMiddleOfLineEndOfLine"** into **"StartOfLineMiddleOfLineEndOf..."** when there is an overflow. How do I this in reverse, making it **"...OfLineMiddleOfLineEndOfLine"**? Is there any workaround? I am ok with **"fLineMiddleOfLineEndOfLine"** without the **"..."** as well.

So far, I can do something slightly ok. Like

```
      <div style="float: right; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;">
        <div>
          StartOfLineMiddleOfLineEndOfLine
        </div>
      </div>
```

This one truncates the prefix, but I want the text to align to the left instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change the direction if you want the ellipsis.

```css
.box {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 120px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis
}
```

```html
<div dir="rtl" class="box">
  StartOfLineMiddleOfLineEndOfLine
</div>
```

And use flexbox if you don't need it:

```css
.box {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 120px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

  StartOfLineMiddleOfLineEndOfLine

</div>
```

Comment: Might wanna increase letter spacing for the second one ?  i can see the `e` being cut off

Comment: @Temani Afif, is the second example the same as 1st example using text-overflow: clip? Which one is better? Thanks

Comment: @BoBoDev the second one is more natural since we keep the normal language direction as we deal with english. The first one may have few drawbacks when dealing with special characters that are affected by the direction change.

Comment: @ZohirSalak in all the cases we will have a letter cut, it would be difficult to avoid this unless we consider monospace font and we define the width as a multiplier of a character width.

Answer (score 0):

As [this article](https://hugogiraudel.com/2014/12/16/css-riddle-reverse-ellipsis/) suggests, `dir="rtl"` will only work in Firefox-based browsers, and in Chrome the right of the text will be clipped as well.

The article suggests a (vaguely) portable CSS-based solution, but it's quite hackish:

```css
    .reverse-ellipsis {
      text-overflow: clip;
      position: relative;
      background-color: white;
    }
    
    .reverse-ellipsis:before {
      content: '\02026';
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 1;
      left: -1em;
      background-color: inherit;
      padding-left: 1em;
      margin-left: 0.5em;
    }
    
    .reverse-ellipsis span {
      min-width: 100%;
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
      float: right;
      overflow: visible;
      background-color: inherit;
      text-indent: 0.5em;
    }
    
    .reverse-ellipsis span:before {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      display: inline-block;
      width: 1em;
      height: 1em;
      background-color: inherit;
      z-index: 200;
      left: -0.5em;
    }
```

```html
<h2>Ellipsis is simple.</h2>
    <div class="box  ellipsis">Here is some long content that doesn't fit.</div>
    <div class="box  ellipsis">Here is some that does fit.</div>
    
    <h2>What about reverse ellipsis?</h2>
    <p>The goal would be to add ellipsis on the beginning and show the end of the content. Any idea?</p>
    <div class="box  ellipsis  reverse-ellipsis"><span>Here is some long content that doesn't fit.</span></div>
    <div class="box  ellipsis  reverse-ellipsis"><span>Here is some that does fit.</span></div>
```

AND the content will still be aligned right *even if it's short enough* to fit in the content.

Comment: RTL is working for me in Chrome latest as of today.